# Using DTF with Installshield and Primary Output

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix, installshield-2012

I have problems with my InstallShield projects, that are using InstallerClasses, during the Major Upgrade. The setup is calling the old version InstallerClass or just throws error 1001.

I decided to use the DTF technology, but I am unable to link the generated *.CA.dll file to the "DLL Filekey" property. I am linking the project as a "primary output".

Any idea how can I use the DTF custom action project and link it to Basic MSI Installshield 2012 project? I want to avoid referencing the CA file directly because I am creating automated builds.

Many thanks,

Marek

Comment: Could you clarify how referencing the file directly conflicts with automated builds? Is it a matter of not knowing the path where the file can be found once it is built, or something more?

Comment: Michael: Yes, I've been strugling with how to link the project generated file from $(OutDir) to IS file table. I was solving it with project link references and including content. But in this case I need a link to the concrete generated file. Is there a nice way to do this? It would also help me to including my C++ primary project outputs. Thank you.